# VAB Insert remote sheetname(s) to a cell in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

sorry for not so clear title, total noob here.

I've have a "for each" loop in order to update values to a single cell for all the sheets in my workbook.

When I try to set something like that:

`Cell.Range("I7").Value = "='Z:\folder...[2022.xlsx]activeSheet.Name'"'!$D$87"`

I can't make the loop to end.

If I put a fixed value, like a number or simple text it will go to the end smoothly. Is there a way to insert that kind of data in order to avoid to do it myself manually?

Thanks!

The code is something like that -->

Option Explicit
Sub insertRowsSheetsWorkbooks()

```
' Disable Excel proprerties before macro runs
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

    ' Declare object variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, iCountRows As Integer, wb As Workbook
    Dim activeSheet As Worksheet, activeRow As Long
    Dim startWorkbook, startSheet As String
    
    
        ' State activeRow
        activeRow = ActiveCell.Row
        
            ' Save initial active workbook & sheet selections
            startWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Name
            startSheet = ThisWorkbook.activeSheet.Name
                    
                        ' Loop through the open workbooks in active Excel
                        For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
                        
                            ' Loop through the worksheets in active workbook
                            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                                ws.Activate
                                    ws.Range("I7").Value = "='Z:\...\[Another_workbook.xlsx]thisWorkbookSheetName'!$D$87"
                                    
                               Next ws
                            
                            ' Move cursor back to initial or left worksheet on current workbook
                            wb.Sheets(1).Select
                            Range("A1").Select
                            
                        Next wb
    ' Move cursor back to initial workbook & worksheet
    Workbooks(startWorkbook).Activate
    Worksheets(startSheet).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
' Re-enable Excel properties once mcaro is complete
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Try sharing the code for the "cycle" and tag your question properly - is this Excel or Google Sheets

Comment: is `activeSheet.Name` a specific sheet in `2022.xlsx` ?

Comment: One line of code doesn't tell us much about what you're actually doing.  And that one line seems to have an extra `"` in it

Comment: This question is total unclear. You tag with Excel and Google-Sheet. You talk about *cycle* (probably you mean a loop), but you don't show any code holding a loop. What do you mean with *"mixed values"*? What happens when your code runs? What do you want to achieve at all? Do you want to write a specific value from another worksheet into a cell or do you want to enter a formula into the cell that references that worksheet?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I've changed the question a little, hoping it will be more clear

Answer (score 0):

may be you're after this

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' ThisWorkbook is the workbook where the running code resides. use ActiveWorkbook if you want to refer to the currently active workbook
        sh.Range("I7").Formula = "='Z:\folder...[2022.xlsx]" & sh.name '" & "!$D$87"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but I get a run-time 1004 error. I've tried ThisWorkbook.Worksheets and ActiveWorkbook